# Changing TextBox ForeColor while it's disabled in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, textbox

I have been working on a Sudoku assignment and have come across a little problem.

I made buttons with the numbers that can be filled in. Now when I press any of these buttons, my method should run through all 81 textboxes on the form, and check it's '.Text' if this equals the button Tag, then I want the textbox' forecolor to be changed to green, whether it's disabled or not.

CODE:

```
Public Sub udsGetal(ByVal strSenderTag As String)
    For intBoxY As Integer = 0 To 2
        For intCellY As Integer = 0 To 2
            For intBoxX As Integer = 0 To 2
                For intCellX As Integer = 0 To 2
                    If getBox(intBoxX, intBoxY).getcell(intCellX, intCellY).text.Equals(strSenderTag) And getBox(intBoxX, intBoxY).getcell(intCellX, intCellY).enabled = True Then
                        getBox(intBoxX, intBoxY).getcell(intCellX, intCellY).forecolor = Color.Green
                    ElseIf getBox(intBoxX, intBoxY).getcell(intCellX, intCellY).text.Equals(strSenderTag) And getBox(intBoxX, intBoxY).getcell(intCellX, intCellY).enabled = False Then
                        getBox(intBoxX, intBoxY).getcell(intCellX, intCellY).enabled = True
                        getBox(intBoxX, intBoxY).getcell(intCellX, intCellY).forecolor()
                        getBox(intBoxX, intBoxY).getcell(intCellX, intCellY).enabled = False
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Sadly, this did not work, I expect this to be because a disabled textbox, can't have it's color changed.

So my question is: Is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: It insists to look disabled when you set Enabled to false.  So don't do that, simply prevent the user from entering text.  Use the KeyPress event, set e.Handled = true.

Comment: That is not what I want to accomplish, in that case I would have to handle the keypress or textchanged method for 81 textboxes. That's very very inefficient in my eyes.

Comment: It is both trivial and efficient, it just takes a single event handler.  Maybe you are ready to move beyond what you know, it isn't very clear from the question.  You'll probably be happier if you derive your own class from TextBox and give it, say, a Frozen property.  Use that property in an override for the OnKeyPress() method.

Comment: I have my own class that inherits the textbox properties. Although I don't see where you want to go yet. As you might understand a sudoku has pre-entered characters which cannot be changed by the player. Then I would need to make extra variables to check if a textbox can be changed or not...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make your textbox "unchangeable" or "uneditable" and want to modify or change its forecolor and backcolor, never use the "enabled = false" property, instead, use "readonly = true." In that case, you may change textbox's forecolor and backcolor.